# NoteProperty in PSObject is not getting populated in Foreach Loop | NSG details export to CSV

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm creating a Azure PS Script which will get all the NSG and then find whether it is attached to Subnet or NIC

When i run the below command it gives output without "Attached To Subnet" column. But when i run the same cmdlet with -ResourceGroupName Property then it gives the output with "Attached to Subnet" and "Attached to Nic" NoteProperty
which is desired.

I'm unable to debug why it is not adding the column "Attached to Subnet" with `Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup`

```
$NSGdetails = @()

Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup | ForEach-Object {

    $D2 = New-Object PSObject

    Write-Host $_.Name 

    $subnet = $_.Subnets.Id
    $nic = $_.NetworkInterfaces.id

    $D2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "NSG Name" -Value $_.Name -Force

    if ($subnet -ne $null) { 
        $subnetdetail = $subnet.Split('/')[-1]
        $D2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Attached To Subnet" -Value $subnetdetail -Force
    }

    if ($nic -ne $null) {
        $nicdetail = $nic.Split('/')[-1]
        $D2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Attached To NIC" -Value $nicdetail -Force
    }

    $NSGdetails += $D2
}

$NSGdetails | Export-Csv -Path "C:\temp\allnicdetails.csv"  -NoTypeInformation -Force
```

Below is the output with `Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup -ResourceGroupName RAH-AQ`

```
PS C:\Users\021176\Desktop> $NSGdetails

NSG Name    Attached To Subnet Attached To NIC
--------    ------------------ ---------------
linuxvm-nsg default            linuxvm15      
redhat-nsg                     redhat396
```

Output with `Get-AzureRmNetworkSecurityGroup` is mentioned below

```
PS C:\Users\021176\Desktop> $NSGdetails

NSG Name       Attached To NIC
--------       ---------------
demolinux-nsg  demolinux76    
devnsg         devnic         
mastesta1-nsg  mastesta1275   
TutorialVM1    TutorialVM1    
filenetapp-nsg filenetapp828  
testvm1NSG                    
nehatest-nsg   nehatest995    
RHEL-nsg       rhel858        
linuxvm-nsg    linuxvm15      
linuxvm-nsg    linuxvm15      
redhat-nsg     redhat396      
SQLBackup-nsg  sqlbackup454   
opnvpntest-nsg opnvpntest764
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Attached To Subnet` property is not ending up in the CSV because only *some* of your objects have that property, and `Export-Csv` decides on which properties to resolve and write based on the *first* input object. Change your code to *always* add the property, regardless of whether there's a value for it:

```
if ($subnet -ne $null) { 
    $subnetdetail = $subnet.Split('/')[-1]
} else {
    $subnetdetail = $null
}
$D2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Attached To Subnet" -Value $subnetdetail -Force

if ($nic -ne $null) {
    $nicdetail = $nic.Split('/')[-1]
} else {
    $nicdetail = $null
}
$D2 | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Attached To NIC" -Value $nicdetail -Force
```